# What is the minimum length of a valid international phone number?

Tags: validation

I need to validate user input of an international phone number. According to [E.164](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164), the maximum length is 15 digits, but I was unable to find any information about the minimum. I consider digits only, no plus sign or separators.

Comment: [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s03.html) shows the minimum is 7

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Comment: @Vega validation of user input is about programming

Answer (score 153):

As per different sources, I think the minimum length in E-164 format depends on country to country. For eg:

- **For Israel**: The minimum phone number length (excluding the
  country code) is 8 digits. - [Official Source](http://www.moc.gov.il/sip_storage/FILES/3/373.pdf)
  (Country Code 972)
- **For Sweden** : The minimum number length (excluding
  the country code) is 7 digits. - [Official Source](http://www.itu.int/dms_pub/itu-t/oth/02/07/T02070000060001MSWE.doc)‎   (country code 46)
- **For Solomon Islands** its 5 for fixed line phones. - [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_Solomon_Islands) (country code 677)

... and so on.
So including country code, the minimum length is 9 digits for Sweden and 11 for Israel and 8 for Solomon Islands.

**Edit (Clean Solution)**: Actually, Instead of validating an international phone number by having different checks like length etc, you can use the **Google's [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) library**. It can validate a phone number in E164 format directly. It will take into account everything and you don't even need to give the country if the number is in valid E164 format. Its pretty good!
Taking an example:

```
String phoneNumberE164Format = "+14167129018"
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
    PhoneNumber phoneNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumberE164Format, null);
    boolean isValid = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(phoneNumberProto); // returns true if valid
    if (isValid) {
        // Actions to perform if the number is valid
    } else {
        // Do necessary actions if its not valid 
    }
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
    System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```

If you know the country for which you are validating the numbers, you don;t even need the E164 format and can specify the country in `.parse` function instead of passing `null`.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I think Google's library also says that "2222" is a valid number, so maybe there should be a minimal length to check.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I tried your above number on libphonenumber.appspot.com. But it said its not a possible number. With which country code did you try that number? Also there are two functions: one which checks if its a possible number and the other which checks if its valid. I don't think we should need a length check.

Comment: Actually when I try that with Israel country code, it shows valid. Maybe you can check the [number types](http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberType.html). `getPhoneType` seems to return UAN. So this 2222 number is UAN. But Universal Access Numbers can also be longer. Technically it seems to be valid number. So either you can check phone number type or a minimum length at your part.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri So what should be the minimal? 7 digits?

Comment: The minimum digits depends on your country. If you want to do it only for Israel, then it would be different. Again it will become the chicken egg problem.

Comment: You may want to update your answer to be minimum 8, for Solomon Islands and Cook Islands - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894899/what-is-the-minimum-length-of-a-valid-international-phone-number/17814276#comment35592897_17734434

Comment: I used this for javascript: https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js

Answer (score 35):

The minimum length is 4 for Saint Helena (Format: +290 XXXX) and Niue (Format: +683 XXXX).

Comment: Saint Helena changed to 5 digits (excluding country code) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Saint_Helena_and_Tristan_da_Cunha

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Niue, Niue only has 7 digits including country code.

Answer (score 18):

**EDIT 2015-06-27: Minimum is actually 8, including country code. My bad.**

*Original post*

The minimum phone number that I use is 10 digits. International users should always be putting their country code, and as far as I know there are no countries with fewer than ten digits if you count country code.

More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbering_plan