# What's the best way to store a phone number in Django models?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-validation

I am storing a phone number in `model` like this:

```
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

The user would enter a phone number and I would use the phone number for *SMS authentication*. This application would be used globally. So I would also need a country code. Is `CharField` a good way to store a phone number? And, how do I validate the phone number?

Comment: There's a great suggestion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1245990/207791

Answer (score 419, accepted):

You might actually look into the internationally standardized format [E.164](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164), [recommended by Twilio for example](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/how-do-i-format-phone-numbers-to-work-internationally) (who have a service and an API for sending SMS or phone-calls via REST requests).

This is likely to be the most universal way to store phone numbers, in particular if you have international numbers work with.

1. Phone by PhoneNumberField

   You can use the `phonenumber_field` library. It is a port of Google's libphonenumber library, which powers Android's phone number handling. See *[django-phonenumber-field](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field)*.

   In the model:

   ```python
   from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

   class Client(models.Model, Importable):
       phone = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
   ```

   In the form:

   ```python
   from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField
   class ClientForm(forms.Form):
       phone = PhoneNumberField()
   ```

   Get the phone as a string from an object field:

   ```python
   client.phone.as_e164
   ```

   Normalize the phone string (for tests and other staff):

   ```python
   from phonenumber_field.phonenumber import PhoneNumber
   phone = PhoneNumber.from_string(phone_number=raw_phone, region='RU').as_e164
   ```
2. Phone by regexp

   One note for your model: E.164 numbers have a maximum character length of 15.

   To validate, you can employ some combination of formatting and then attempting to contact the number immediately to verify.

   I believe I used something like the following in my django project:

   ```
    class ReceiverForm(forms.ModelForm):
        phone_number = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                                        error_message = ("Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits is allowed."))
   ```

---

As per [jpotter6](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1736429/jpotter6), you can do something like the following in your models as well:

File *models.py*:

```python
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class PhoneModel(models.Model):
    ...
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True) # Validators should be a list
```

Comment: It might be valuable to show how to do this on a model as well.


phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")




phone_number = models.CharField(validators=phone_regex, blank=True)

Comment: @jpotter6 Your comment would be a great supplementary answer to this question.

Comment: Don't forget to add 'max_length=15' to the models.CharField

Comment: @Esteban - max_length=16 (there is an optional + at the start)

Comment: @erewok - I don't believe you want the '1' in your regex. E.164 allows up to 15 digits, inclusive of the country code.

Comment: Indeed, E.164 does not include any international call prefixes, only the country code followed by the actual number, also the [minimum length of an E.164 number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14894899/343834) seems to be 8 so the regex should be `'^\+\d{8,15}$'` and then `max_length=16` for the `CharField`.

Comment: When using thte phonenumber_field library remember to first pip install django-phonenumber-field[phonenumbers]

Comment: can you help me to handle user when search using national format but in database phone formated e164 ?

if you can plese help me solve my problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75274216/store-phone-field-use-django-phonenumber-field-override-search-method-to-e164-fo) thanks before.

Answer (score 66):

Use [django-phonenumber-field](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field):

```
pip install django-phonenumber-field
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the region.  Without `PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION = 'US'` in the settings it won't allow you to input anything users from the United States would recognize as a phone number.  Even then, this package won't output as something that looks like a phone number . . . I'm sure there's a setting I just haven't found yet!

Comment: Note: this package is very big. Over 40MB. 33MB of it is geodata.

Comment: Noting @Forethinker 's comment, a much more lightweight alternative is https://github.com/VeryApt/django-phone-field , via `pip install django-phone-field`

Comment: @Forethinker then we can use the "lite" version `pip install django-phonenumber-field[phonenumberslite]` which  does not include the geocoding, carrier and timezone metadata

Comment: hey here how do you update the phone_number because i am getting error as Can't convert tuple to PhoneNumber.

Answer (score 9):

Use a `CharField` for the phone field in the model and the `localflavor` app for form validation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/localflavor/

As of 2021-12-07, it looks like [LocalFlavor](https://pypi.org/project/django-localflavor/) is no longer part of Django.

Comment: I agree with @rgenito now (for Django 3.x), and I'm currently I'm using the `django-phonenumber-field` (with `phonenumbers`).

Comment: the link is broken.

Answer (score 9):

First, install **"django-phonenumber-field" package** with the command below:

```
pip install django-phonenumber-field[phonenumbers]
```

Then, set **"phonenumber_field"** to **INSTALLED_APPS** in **"settings.py"**:

```py
# "settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "phonenumber_field",
    ...
]
```

Then, set a field with **"PhoneNumberField()"** in **"models.py"**:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class Contact(models.Model):
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
```

Then, register **"Contact"** in **"admin.py"**:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Contact

@admin.register(Contact)
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Then, run the command below:

```
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
```

Now, the field for a phone number is created as shown below:

[image]

In addition, assign **the widget "PhoneNumberPrefixWidget()"** to the field in a custom form and assign the custom form to the admin as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Contact
from django import forms
from phonenumber_field.widgets import PhoneNumberPrefixWidget

class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'phone': PhoneNumberPrefixWidget(),
        }

@admin.register(Contact)
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ContactForm
```

Now, with country codes, the field for a phone number is created

[image]

And, you can set an initial country code like **initial='US'** to **"PhoneNumberPrefixWidget()"** as shown below. *Initial country code must be uppercase:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Contact
from django import forms
from phonenumber_field.widgets import PhoneNumberPrefixWidget

class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {                          # Here
            'phone': PhoneNumberPrefixWidget(initial='US'),
        }

@admin.register(Contact)
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ContactForm
```

Now, with **the initial country code "US" selected**, the field for a phone number is created:

[image]

You can also set an initial country code with **"PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION"** in **"settings.py"** as shown below but I recommand to set an initial country code with **initial='US'** to **"PhoneNumberPrefixWidget()"** as I've done above because using **"PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION"** sometimes doesn't display saved phone numbers in **Django Admin**:

```py
# "settings.py"

PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION = "US"
```

Comment: thanks thus was really helpful. worked exactly how i wanted it.

Answer (score 8):

Validation is easy. Text them a little code to type in.

A CharField is a great way to store it. I wouldn't worry too much about canonicalizing phone numbers.

Comment: best answer.  Let the clients do the validation.

Answer (score 8):

This solution worked for me:

First install *django-phone-field*. Command:

```
pip install django-phone-field
```

Then in file *models.py*:

```
from phone_field import PhoneField
...

class Client(models.Model):
    ...
    phone_number = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Contact phone number')
```

And in file *settings.py*:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [...,
                  'phone_field'
]
```

It looks like this in the end:

[image: Phone in form]

Comment: hello, how do you remove the ext input form? i only want the contact phone number without ext

Answer (score 3):

Others mentioned `django-phonenumber-field`. To get the display format how you want you need to set `PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_FORMAT` setting to `"E164"`, `"INTERNATIONAL"`, `"NATIONAL"`, or `"RFC3966"`, however you want it displayed. See the [GitHub source](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field/blob/3.0.1/phonenumber_field/phonenumber.py#L34).

Answer (score 2):

```
1)
# Installs phonenumbers minimal metadata
pip install "django-phonenumber-field[phonenumberslite]"
# Installs phonenumbers extended features (e.g. geocoding)
pip install "django-phonenumber-field[phonenumbers]

I recommend using that pip install "django-phonenumber-field[phonenumbers]"

2) models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True, region='IR')

3) Settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'

4)forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from phonenumber_field.widgets import PhoneNumberPrefixWidget


# from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        widgets = {
            'phone': PhoneNumberPrefixWidget(),
        }

        # fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields +('phone',) 
        fields = ['phone']
        
    
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        widgets = {
            'phone': PhoneNumberPrefixWidget(),
        }
        # fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields +('phone',) 
        fields = ['phone']

Important : Requires the Babel package be installed.

5)admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm


@admin.register(get_user_model())
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model =get_user_model()
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    list_display = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'phone'
    ]
    
    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets +(
        (None,{'fields':('phone',),}),
    )
    
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets +(
        (None,{'fields':('phone',),}),
    )
    
# admin.site.register(get_user_model(), CustomUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you understand as a phone number. Phone numbers are country-specific. The localflavors packages for several countries contains their own "phone number field". So if you are OK being country-specific you should take a look at localflavor package (`class us.models.PhoneNumberField` for the US case, etc.)

Otherwise you could inspect the localflavors to get the maximum length for all countries. Localflavor also has forms fields you could use in conjunction with the country code to validate the phone number.

Comment: Hm Yes, I found that while I did a research. Can you give an example on how to use it in a form.

Answer (score 1):

I will describe what I use:

Validation: The string contains more than 5 digits.

Cleaning: removing all non-digit symbols and writing only numbers to the database. I'm lucky, because in my country (Russia) everybody has phone numbers with 10 digits. So I store only 10 digits in the database. If you are writing a multi-country application, then you should make a comprehensive validation.

Rendering: I write a custom template tag to render nicely it in the template. Or even render it like a picture - it is safer to prevent SMS spam.

Comment: Stumbling across this a few years later, but depending on platform (Web, in this case, I assume), I argue against rendering as a picture, even if it helps prevent spam. It's very inaccessible. It can't be copy'pasted, it can't be zoomed-in and maintain clarity, and it can't be ready by screen readers. https://www.boia.org/blog/why-is-it-important-for-accessibility-to-use-actual-text-instead-of-images-of-text

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to install the phone number Django package.

```
pip install django-phonenumber-field[phonenumbers]
```

Then next is to add it to the installed applications:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'phonenumber_field',
    ...
]
```

This is how to use it in your model:

```
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class Artist(models.Model):

    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
```