# python regex remove all non-numberic characters and ensure valid phone number

Tags: python, regex, django

I'd like to move all of my phone number validation into one django validator field. How can I use this [phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130942/whats-the-best-way-to-store-phone-number-in-django-models) validator to include stripping all non numeric fields in the string?

e.g. '123.123.1234' would become '1231231234'

I know you can do it with a replace such as `replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" )` but it needs to be one regex for the django validator

```
validate_phone_number = RegexValidator(
    regex=re.compile(r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$'),
    message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.",
    code='invalid'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can do that really ... however you could probably specify the form input as only numeric (perhaps with `forms.IntegerField`)

or you could write your own validator

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_numeric(value):
    if not (9 <= len(re.sub("[^0-9]","",value)) <= 15):
        raise ValidationError('%s is not a valid phone number' % value)
```