# Equivalent Form field for Model field Bigintegerfield in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Django has an inbuilt Model field called `BigIntegerField`, but it does not have a corresponding Form field, and there is only an `IntegerField` available for use with forms. Is there any problem with this mismatch? That is using `BigIntegerField` in the model and `IntegerField` for the model form.

I want to store phone numbers in these fields (10-digits), so the `IntegerField` Model class cannot store all positive 10-digit values as it is only up to 2147483647.

Comment: Why storing phone numbers in a integer field? Why not charfield.

Comment: I suggest you to use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19131360/6396981

Comment: @durdenk I want the input to be limited to numbers and use default django backend validation to exclude characters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @SancaKembang