# Custom Filter in Django admin

Tags: python, django, filter, admin

I have a model as follows

```
class Person:
  name = models.CharField()
  city = models.CharField()
  phone = models.CharField()
```

I want to create a filter in the admin page, the filter should be based on phone, that is

```
valid phone(having 10 digits)
invalid phone
```

I don't want to create a validation. I just want to filter out who has a valid phone and invalid. 
Thanks

Comment: did you look for phonenumber-field:  https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field ?

Comment: Or you could try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19131360/3848720

Comment: @BearBrown I didn't get you. I can create a normal filter using "list_filter" but this will bring me the whole no, instead I want to customized the filter to show me the valid phone numbers and invalid phone numbers separately. I don't want to put validation while saving it.

Comment: @tdsymonds I don't want to put validation. I just want to know among the saved no's which one is valid and which one isn't. I want to see this filter in the admin page

Comment: do you need html template filter?

Comment: @BearBrown I dont know that but what I know is I want to create a filter in the admin page which will show me users with invalid phone no and valid no. Only the admin need to have this privilege

Answer (score 7):

Create a custom list filter class. There's an [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)
 which can be adopted to your case.

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ValidPhoneListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    # Human-readable title which will be displayed in the
    # right admin sidebar just above the filter options.
    title = _('valid phone')

    parameter_name = 'valid_phone'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('valid', _('valid phone')),
            ('invalid', _('invalid phone')),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() == 'valid':
            return queryset.filter(phone__regex=r'^\d{10}$')
        if self.value() == 'invalid':
            return queryset.exclude(phone__regex=r'^\d{10}$')
```

Then include your list filter class in `list_filter` for your model admin.

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (ValidPhoneListFilter,)
```

Comment: Thanks I think this will work. Let me check it out and will come back to you

Comment: The filter has come in the right side with option of valid and Invalid but the filter is not working as planned. Clicking valid will give no values and clicking Invalid will give all the values. I think the problem is in the regular expression. please check it once and let me know.  your answer is the closest i found

Comment: The regex appears to be ok to me - `import re; re.search(r'^\d{10}$', '0123456789')` returns a match.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

phone_regex = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9]{10}$', 'Invalid phone number')
```

And in your model

```
phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex])
```

This regex only checks if it is digits and that the length is 10. Modify it after your specific needs.

Hope this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your time but I don't want to put validator. I just need to be able to filter out as admin