# How to make integer field fixed to ten numbers output in models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want user to input their phone numbers with 10 digits, how to set integer field "phone_no" in order to achieve it ?

I have set it to default but I want to check number input :

models.py

```
class Documents(models.Model):
    docs_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Names in Documents")
    item_type = models.CharField(default="", max_length=100,
                             help_text='*Enter the item name you found e.g. Marksheet,key,wallet',verbose_name="Item type" )
    police_station = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='*Enter the police station you sending the docs', verbose_name="Police station")
    phone_no = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Phone number")
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,verbose_name="Date")
    Description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='*Enter full description about item',verbose_name="Description")
    pay_no = models.IntegerField(default=0,verbose_name="payment number")
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    image = models.ImageField(default="add Item image",
                          upload_to="DocsImage",blank=False, verbose_name="Images")


"""docstring for Documents"""
def __str__(self):
    return self.docs_name
```

Comment: are you sure to use an IntegerField for the phone number ? what if it begins with 0 ?

Comment: any way to achieve it, and of course it starts with zero. Please help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/) to achieve this. They are functions (or any callable) that you can plug in the Field declaration to check some conditions.

Firstly, in this case, you should use a `models.CharField(verbose_name="Phone number"...)` to store the phone number, in case they begin by 0.

Next we have to perform tests to check if the value contains only digits, and only 10.

### Option 1: Custom validator

The first way is to create the validator yourself in order to run the tests you want exactly:

- Create the function that will raise an error if the tests fail :

  ```
  def validate_digit_length(phone):
      if not (phone.isdigit() and len(phone) == 10):    
          raise ValidationError('%(phone)s must be 10 digits', params={'phone': phone},)
  ```

  You can store this function next to the model, or in a separate file and import it.
- Then plug this function in the field declaration, on the parameter `validators` (type list) :

  ```
  phone_no = models.CharField(verbose_name="Phone number", max_length=10,  
      validators=[validate_digit_length], default='1234567890')
  ```

### Option 2: Use Built-in validators

You can also find [built-in validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#built-in-validators)  in django, for all the generic cases.

With this Charfield `phone_no`, the `max_length` parameter will check the max size, so we need to check the minimum size (10) and if characters are digits. We can achieve this with [`MinLengthValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#minlengthvalidator) and [`int_list_validator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#int-list-validator) :

```
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator, int_list_validator

phone_no = models.CharField(verbose_name="Phone number", max_length=10,
    validators=[int_list_validator(sep=''),MinLengthValidator(10),], 
    default='1234567890')
```

---

Another link to explore :
[What's the best way to store Phone number in Django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130942/whats-the-best-way-to-store-phone-number-in-django-models)