# How to add custom field like phone number in User model in django so that it can be used in UserCreationForm?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, backend

I want to save user phone number upon sign up. How can i add phone number in user creation form?

If i create a separate model known as UserContact, then how can i add this field in UserCreationForm so that when it is submitted it gets saved to the corresponding models?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130942/whats-the-best-way-to-store-phone-number-in-django-models

Comment: i'm asking about extending user model to include phone number field so that it can be used in user creation form