# How do I add phone number field to django UserCreationForm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to add PhoneNumberField so I can use take phone number of user at time registration. I already have UserCreationForm model which is used by CreateUserForm to create a new User. However by default it does not phone number field. I tried adding it by adding phone variable in forms.py but it does not work giving the error below.

forms.py

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    phone=PhoneNumberField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'phone']
```

models.py

```
class CustomerReg(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    phone=PhoneNumberField(default=None)
def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile=CustomerReg.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

This is Error I get when I run python manage.py makemigrations

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\djangoL2G\venvP\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\djangoL2G\venvP\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\djangoL2G\venvP\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\djangoL2G\venvP\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 368, in execute
    self.check()
  File "D:\djangoL2G\venvP\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "D:\djangoL2G\venvP\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "D:\djangoL2G\venvP\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "D:\djangoL2G\venvP\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "D:\djangoL2G\venvP\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "D:\djangoL2G\venvP\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\djangoL2G\venvP\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "D:\djangoL2G\venvP\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\djangoL2G\venvP\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\DjangoL2Gwiz\l2gproject\l2gProject\urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('',include('customer.urls')),
  File "D:\djangoL2G\venvP\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\DjangoL2Gwiz\l2gproject\customer\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "D:\DjangoL2Gwiz\l2gproject\customer\views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .forms import CreateUserForm
  File "D:\DjangoL2Gwiz\l2gproject\customer\forms.py", line 35, in <module>
    class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  File "D:\djangoL2G\venvP\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 268, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (phone) specified for User
```

How do I add phone number field to my form then?

Comment: would this help you answer your query? 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130942/whats-the-best-way-to-store-phone-number-in-django-models]

Comment: It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest doing something like this:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
   phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
   phone = forms.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17)
   class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'phone']
```