# Cannot Update Custom User (AbstractUser)

Tags: django, abstractuser

I am using a custom user model which inherits from the AbstractUser and when I save a user it works well.
But whenI need to update the model and I click on my submit button on my template nothing happens. Nothing shows in the console, the page does not reload, nothing.
I would really appreciate some guidance here?

```py
#models 
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from sos.models import Company 
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.urls import reverse  # page 138 Django for Beginneers 

# Create your models here.

#  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130942/whats-the-best-way-to-store-phone-number-in-django-models/19131360

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True )   
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True )
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    mobile_phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=False, null=True, unique=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Is Staff Admin?", help_text="Designates whether this user should be able to log in the Admin Interface.")
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company , on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Company Name") 
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("customuser_detail", args=[str(self.id)])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["username"]
```

```py
# forms
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from .models import CustomUser
from .models import UserTargets

# cripsy forms imports 
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Column, Layout, Field, Fieldset, Div, Row, HTML, ButtonHolder, Submit
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import TabHolder, Tab

#  3rd Party
from .custom_layout_object import Formset

# forms 

from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory 

import re


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    password = None 

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'
        # fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1','password2','is_staff', 'is_active' ,'email','position','mobile_phone','is_active','company')
        # fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('email','position','mobile_phone','company')
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False # use false if you want to render the form tags manually
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-10'
        self.helper.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(

                Div(
                    Field('username'),
                    Field('first_name'),
                    Field('last_name'),
                    # Field('password'),
                    # Field('password2'),
                    Field('email'),
                    Field('position'),
                    Field('is_staff'),
                    Field('is_active'),
                    Field('mobile_phone'),
                    Field('company'),

                HTML("<br>"),
                ButtonHolder(Submit('submit', 'Save', css_class='btn btn-primary btn-xs')),
                
                )
        )
```

```py
# views

class CustomUserUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = CustomUser
    form_class = CustomUserChangeForm
    template_name = 'accounts/user_profiles/customuser_edit.html'
```

```py
#urls 
 path('profiles/<int:pk>/edit', views.CustomUserUpdateView.as_view() , name='customuser_edit'),
```

```py
# templates
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}

{% block extrahead %}

  {{ form.media }}

  {% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            Edit User Profile  
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            {% csrf_token %}
             {% crispy form %}

             <br>           
             <a> <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" /></a>
             <a href="{% url 'customuser_list' %}"> |All Users </a>
         </div>
    </div>  
 </div>
<!--  https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/issues/65  -->

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Where is the form tag??

Comment: I am using Django crispy forms so the form tag is rendered using the crispy form.

Comment: `self.helper.form_tag = False # use false if you want to render the form tags manually` this is a line in your own code...

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying in your last comment Abdul.

Answer (score 0):

After the page has been rendered, view page source.
check if crispy form actually included the form tags.

i have not used crispy forms before but i have to ask, shouldn't you somehow descripbe where the form ends?

maybe you are missing something to the tune of...

```
{% end crispy forms %}
```