# django-rest-auth with allauth customuser TypeError: 'PhoneNumber' object is not subscriptable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
```

payloads:

```
{
  "username": "+8801700000000",
  "password1": "demo",
  "password2": "demo",
  "email": "demo@demo.com",
}
```

response:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/rest-auth/registration/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\rest_auth\registration\views.py", line 46, in dispatch
    return super(RegisterView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 190, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\rest_auth\registration\views.py", line 65, in create
    user = self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\rest_auth\registration\views.py", line 73, in perform_create
    user = serializer.save(self.request)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\rest_auth\registration\serializers.py", line 210, in save
    adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\adapter.py", line 242, in save_user
    self.populate_username(request, user)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\adapter.py", line 209, in populate_username
    user_username(
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\utils.py", line 120, in user_username
    return user_field(user, app_settings.USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD, *args)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\utils.py", line 110, in user_field
    v = v[0:max_length]
TypeError: 'PhoneNumber' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this problem because all auth try to subscribe the username  by using slicing i recommend to try the following

```
phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True) # validators should be a list
```

this token from
[What's the best way to store Phone number in Django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130942/whats-the-best-way-to-store-phone-number-in-django-models)

Comment: `CharField` will solve problem. But any way using `phonenumberfield`? Only rest-auth creates problem but default allauth registration works nicely

Comment: in this case, you will need to rewrite the utils.py in allauth