# Creating a sequential file

Tags: c++, file, sequential

I'm trying to create a sequential file but it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone explain how to get this to work in MS Visual Studio 2010?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream outClientFile( "clients.dat", ios::out);

    if (!outClientFile)
    {
        cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "Enter the Appointment Date, Time, Duration, Name," << endl
        << "Description, Contact Name, and Contact Number.\n? "; 

    int appDate, appTime, appContactNum;
    string appName, appDescription, appContactName;
    double appDuration;

    while ( cin >> appDate >> appTime >> appDuration >>
        appName >> appDescription >> appContactName >> appContactNum )
    {
        outClientFile << appDate << ' ' << appTime << ' ' << appDuration << ' ' << appName << ' ' << appDescription << ' ' << appContactName << ' ' << appContactNum << endl;
        cout << "? ";
    }
}
```

And here is the output after I enter one line.

```
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
The program '[452] CSC275 Assignment 3.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Could you cite an example of the input you're using?

Comment: Here's the input I'm using: 03062011 1030 2.5 Dentist Cleaning Joshua 5552492131

Comment: I may have gotten it to work. I just changed my int variables to doubles.

Comment: Yes, a signed 32-bit int would not be able to hold 5552492131.  You might want to use a string instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an `int` to store 10-digit telephone numbers, as the 'largest' telephone number you could store would be (in `signed int`) `2147483647` or (in an `unsigned int`) `4294967295`. Neither of these are large enough to store a phone number from my home state with area codes `503`, `541`, or `971`. [Strings are probably best for storing phone numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723587/whats-the-longest-possible-worldwide-phone-number-i-should-consider-in-sql-varch), as they expand to handle phone numbers from Czech Republic or American Samoa and so forth.

I'm also leery of using `double` for storing anything other than mathematics, scientific data or physics simulations. I may be a little paranoid about this, as most applications that use `double` in this respect mostly get away with it, but `double`s store data exactly until you slightly push outside their bounds, at which point they store data very approximately indeed.

Comment: Ok. Now when I go to read the file I create the date is printed as "5903ED4803062011" and thats when I store the date as a string variable. Why does it do this and how can I fix it?

Comment: @Joshua, thanks; I'm curious to know how you fixed the problem in the end. :)

Comment: It's funny. I actually had two cout's. So my code looked like this:
`cout << cout <<`

Comment: @Joshua, heh, I wonder how long it would have taken me to find that. :)