# Validate Mobile number with the country code

Tags: android, validation, phone-number

I want to validate the mobile number user enters. I have two edit texts one for the code i.e. +91,0 etc and another for the phone number.

I have a question that how to stop entering the numbers in edit text if more than 10 numbers being entered by the user. Also it should get validated with code and the number.

I tried the validation with this code.

```
 private boolean isValidMobile(String phone)
{
    return android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(phone).matches();
}

 else if (!isValidMobile(code.getText().toString()+mobileNo.getText().toString()))
            {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Please enter correct Mobile No.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

But it dose not return true for the number. Always returns false i.e. please enter the correct number.

edit texts for number :

```
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText_code"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="+91"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:phoneNumber="true" />


      <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:hint="MOBILE NO"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayoutFirstName"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
                android:id="@+id/mobileNo"
                android:phoneNumber="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

How to do this? Thank you.

Comment: try code.getText().toString()+"-"+mobileNo.getText().toString()

Comment: tried. dose not help.@USKMobility

Answer (score 1):

Try this Example...

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtCountryCode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:hint="country_code"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtPhoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/edtCountryCode"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:hint="phone_no"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvIsValidPhone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edtPhoneNumber"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnValidate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvIsValidPhone"
    android:text="validate"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.NumberParseException;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil;
import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.Phonenumber;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvIsValidPhone;
EditText edtPhone;
EditText edtCountryCode;
Button btnValidate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvIsValidPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIsValidPhone);
    edtCountryCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCountryCode);
    edtPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPhoneNumber);
    btnValidate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnValidate);
    btnValidate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String countryCode = edtCountryCode.getText().toString().trim();
            String phoneNumber = edtPhone.getText().toString().trim();
            if(countryCode.length() > 0 && phoneNumber.length() > 0){
                if(isValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)){
                    boolean status = validateUsing_libphonenumber(countryCode, phoneNumber);
                    if(status){
                        tvIsValidPhone.setText("Valid Phone Number (libphonenumber)");
                    } else {
                        tvIsValidPhone.setText("Invalid Phone Number (libphonenumber)");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    tvIsValidPhone.setText("Invalid Phone Number (isValidPhoneNumber)");
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Country Code and Phone Number is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private boolean isValidPhoneNumber(CharSequence phoneNumber) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber)) {
        return Patterns.PHONE.matcher(phoneNumber).matches();
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean validateUsing_libphonenumber(String countryCode, String phNumber) {
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    String isoCode = phoneNumberUtil.getRegionCodeForCountryCode(Integer.parseInt(countryCode));
    Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber = null;
    try {
        //phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.parse(phNumber, "IN");  //if you want to pass region code
        phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.parse(phNumber, isoCode);
    } catch (NumberParseException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }

    boolean isValid = phoneNumberUtil.isValidNumber(phoneNumber);
    if (isValid) {
        String internationalFormat = phoneNumberUtil.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Phone Number is Valid " + internationalFormat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Phone Number is Invalid " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
}}
```

Download jar file and add in libs folder from below link..
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/l/Downloadlibphonenumber41jar.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `isGlobalPhoneNumber()` method of `PhoneNumberUtils` to detect whether a number is valid phone number or not.

Comment: Because method you use is not so correct (didn't flag appropriate phone number as a valid)