# Does CountryCodePicker support entering phone number

Tags: android

I'm using `CountryCodePicker` in my code where the user can select the country he's in and supposedly enter he's phone number, so does this control support entering phone number or do I have to use `EditText` view?

Also, say I'll have to use `EditText`, does this control support checking a phone number validity?

```
    <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
        android:id="@+id/ccpicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        app:ccp_defaultLanguage="ENGLISH"
        app:ccp_defaultPhoneCode="54"
        app:ccp_showNameCode="false"
        app:ccp_rememberLastSelection="true" />
```

Comment: No, you have to add a edittext to enter mobile number

Comment: How to check the validity of the entered number in the EditText?

Comment: This is critical point, every country have their different telephone numbering plan. Now you can do one thing which set a universal limit 4 to 15 for all phone number in the world. but this is not the appropriate way. If you set phone length according to country code, it will takes time and efforts.

Comment: Find any library if it is available you can easily integrate it

Comment: check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765271/validate-mobile-number-with-the-country-code
may helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and I hope it will help others.

CountryCodePicker  supports binding to an EditText view to enter the phone number, and an override to check the validity of the phone number.

Add CCP view and editText of carrier number to XML layout

```
              <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical">

                  <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
                      android:id="@+id/ccp"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      app:ccp_countryPreference="us,in"
                      />

                  <EditText
                      android:id="@+id/editText_carrierNumber"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:editable="false"
                      android:hint="phone"
                      android:inputType="phone"
                      android:singleLine="true" />
              </LinearLayout>
```

Add CCP object in Activity / Fragment

```
CountryCodePicker ccp;
EditText editTextCarrierNumber;
```

Bind CCP and Carrier Number editText from layout

```
ccp = (CountryCodePicker) findViewById(R.id.ccp);
editTextCarrierNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_carrierNumber);
```

Attach CarrierNumber editText to CCP.

```
ccp.registerCarrierNumberEditText(editTextCarrierNumber);
```

Validity Change Listener will get callBack every time validity of entered number changes.

```
ccp.setPhoneNumberValidityChangeListener(new CountryCodePicker.PhoneNumberValidityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValidityChanged(boolean isValidNumber) {
               // your code
            }
        });
```

Reference: https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/wiki/Full-Number-Support#3-number-validation

Comment: I just tried this in kotlin. There are no errors, but the editText will actually show the full number