# Android: Validate Phone Number Length by COUNTRY

Tags: android, validation, phone-number, telephony, mobile-country-code

How can we validate the length of a mobile number by COUNTRY?
(Knowing that the country code might or might not be part of the number)

Length may vary per country, meaning there should be a length range or pattern validator.

Example:

- +1 222 2222 222 (13 digits) Valid ✔️
- 222 2222 222 (12 digits) Valid only if chosen in corresponding Locale ✔️
- +1 222 2222 2222222 (17 digits) Invalid ❌
- +1 222 2222 (8 digits) Invalid ❌

Note: Any idea where can I find each country's mobile number length range.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765271/validate-mobile-number-with-the-country-code

Comment: Hello @DarShan I need to check any mobile number if it's length is in range for every country. So, I might need a list that contains all countries with the expected calid length. P.S.: I cannot use libraries for security reasons.

Comment: The link redirects you to a complete example on SO, it’s not a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin answer

```
val swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00"
val phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance()

try {

    val swissNumberPrototype = phoneUtil.parse(swissNumberStr, "CH")

    val isValid = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(swissNumberPrototype)

    if (isValid) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }

} catch (e: NumberParseException) {
    System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: $e")
}
```

Comment: phoneUtil.isValidNumber() is the correct way of checking if the phone number is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Given the mobile number and the country code, you can use [libphonenumeer](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber) which is a Google library for validating phone numbers; it checks the number length and catches `NumberParseException` exception if it is not a right number.

This is their sample in how to use it

```
String swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00";
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
  PhoneNumber swissNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(swissNumberStr, "CH");
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
  System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Hello @Zain, so if the input is swissNumberStr="044 668 1" for example, the exception is thrown? I tried parsing a shorter (invalid) number and the exception was not thrown. I need phoneUtil.parse("044 688 1","CH"); to throw an exception. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Zain 's answer.

```
String swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00";
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
  PhoneNumber swissNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(swissNumberStr, "CH");
//  This will check if the phone number is real and its length is valid.
  boolean isPossible = phoneUtil.isPossibleNumber(swissNumberProto);
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
  System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```