# Constraint for phone number in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints

Constraint for phone number to be of 7 digits. How to check if it is of 7 digits in SQL Server?

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    C_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    C_Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Phone INT 
);
```

Comment: You don't need to store phone numbers as integers. You will never be doing math on phone numbers. Store them as varchar. You can easily add a constraint to check LEN = 7 and value not like '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'

Comment: try decimal(7,0) which trows error for storing more length

Comment: it worked with Phone VARCHAR CHECK(DATALENGTH(Phone)=7)

Comment: You could make it CHAR(7), but I think your desired constraint is a bad idea in the first place. In the US, for example, phone numbers are actually 10 digits with the first three being optional. When dealing with foreign countries, you may want to store the country code along with however many digits the number is.

Comment: What happens when an Australian person wants to store their phone number? In that country, phone numbers can be up to 8 characters.

Comment: @Greenstone Walker: Bottom line is, a phone-number can have  5+15+11 = 31 digits. So it doesn't fit into a bigint, not an unsigned either. This fits into Decimal(31,0), because decimal can have up to 38 digits. And you need a number to enforce that idiots don't safe garbage into it.

Comment: @Sean Lange: Storing it as number ensures no garbage is entered. int or long (aka bigint) are far too small to store the 31 digits required for an arbitrary maximum-length-phone-number. You need decimal(31,0), and you need a check-constraint to ensure negative numbers are NOT used.

Comment: @StefanSteiger but the OP specifically asked for a constraint that would only allow 7 digits. I agree 10000% about your comments for a phone number but the OP didn't want that.

Comment: @Sean Lange:  For that, an integer is sufficient, you just need to set minimum and maximum in a check constraint. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @StefanSteiger why would you want an integer to store a phone number?

Comment: @Sean Lange: To be 100% sure you can't store any garbage in it. So you can actually use the number if you have to send a SMS...

Comment: @StefanSteiger that's why you would use a constraint. Also for SMS you typically want to include the country code so you need something like "+1 1234567890". I guess we will have to agree to disagree about datatypes for phone numbers. I side with the dozens and dozens of people who for decades have agreed that phone numbers should be strings.

Comment: @Sean Lange: Yes, you need to add the + in front when you save it as number. If you save it as string, you absolutely have to put thorough check-constraints in, and maybe you can allow dash and space, but the more you allow, the more certain you will have a worthless field. And one thing I can guarantee you: if you don't have the constraint at DB level, data garbage will enter really soon. By the way, some people also might resort to disable the constraint, instead of fixing the problem. They can't if it's a numeric field.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do not store phone numbers as integers.  Some valid numbers, for instance, could start with a 0 -- if not today, perhaps in the future.  To do the validation check, you can use `like`:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    C_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    C_Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Phone CHAR(7), -- you might not want to have such a precise length
    CONSTRAINT chk_phone CHECK (phone not like '%[^0-9]%') -- check that no number is not a digit 
);
```

Alternatively, you could write:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_phone CHECK (phone like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') -- check that no number is not a digit
```

Comment: If i use the check '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' and insert a 10 digit string it says i violate the check constraint.

Comment: NOTE: In your last line, you should replace 'phone like' with 'phone not like'. I am unable to edit your post and fix this issue, so i'm leaving this note

Comment: Can somebody please explain why are the `%` wildcards required in this case? Isn't `[^0-9]` already searching for any non-digit character?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a student table. In order to check the contact length, the following code works:

```
ALTER TABLE Student ADD CONSTRAINT SD_CHK check(contact like '[0-9]*10');
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: if i do an insert value of '1234567890' I get the error that it violates the check constraint for your code.

Answer (score 0):

it worked with Phone VARCHAR CHECK(DATALENGTH(Phone)=7)

Answer (score 0):

You'd better store phone number as **varchar2** or **char** type. In Oracle, you can check the validation of phone number by **Regular Expression:**

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    C_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    C_Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Phone char(10),
    CONSTRAINT valid_phone_number 
    CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(p_number, '^0\d{9}|\d{10}$'))
);
```

> ***'^0\d{9}|\d{10}$'*** means phone number must start with digit 0, then followed by 9 or 10 digits (i.e 01646947314 (11 digits) or 0123456789 (10 digits) is VALID, and 123456789 or 0123456 is not valid). You can modify this code to 7 digits by dropping "|" in regular expression and change to d{7}. 
>   Hope this help you (or someone else's having the similar problem)!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [NANP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan), seven-digit phone numbers in the US are NXX-XXXX, where N is 2-9 and X is 0-9.  Additionally the second and third numbers cannot both be 1.  Assuming you want to store only real NANP phone numbers, you could use the following constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Customer
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Phone_valid
CHECK (Phone >= 2000000 AND Phone <= 9999999 and Phone / 10000 % 100 <> 11)
```

If you wanted to add an area code, you would need to use a bigint and different/additional constraints.  Additionally, any sort in internal phone numbers, extensions, area codes, international phone numbers, etc., will have different requirements.

As someone who frequently deals with a large number of (exclusively NANP) phone numbers in databases, I do find that keeping them in a number format is ideal, as it is faster, smaller, and has the added benefit of preventing various formatting problems by default.  Though for most users, this is probably all moot.

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing. 
If you really really just want a constraint that enforces exactly 7 digits, then you can do this:

```
DECLARE @phone TABLE 
(
     phone_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
    ,phone_name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL 
    ,phone_number int NULL CHECK 
    (
        phone_number >= 1000000 -- or > 999999
        AND 
        phone_number <= 9999999 -- or < 10000000    
    ) 
);



INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
SELECT 1 AS phone_id, N'Person 1' AS pn, '1000000' AS phone_number; 

INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
SELECT 2 AS phone_id, N'Person 2' AS pn, '9999999' AS phone_number; 


INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
SELECT 3 AS phone_id, N'Person 3' AS pn, '+1000000' AS phone_number;
```

Now, if you ever need the preceding zeroes, you can just do:

```
SELECT RIGHT(('0000000') + CAST(phone_number as varchar(32)), 7) AS number FROM @phone
```

However, if you just end up here from a google-search looking for a constraint for a phone-number in general...

then, I've just been thinking about what the correct constraint for a phone number would be.

Looking at [questions 723587](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723587/whats-the-longest-possible-worldwide-phone-number-i-should-consider-in-sql-varc), I was able to determine that the maximum-length a phone-number can have is **31** digits.

**Given that we have the need to send SMS, which means it has to be a valid-number to send**, I figured the best "constraint" to prevent people from littering the field with garbage is to declare it as decimal(31, 0). You can also put a check-constraint in there to enfore a minimum-length for the phone number (minimum-number). Also, you need to check that the number is not less than zero.

If you absolutely want to do it with varchar, then looking at Gordon Linoff's post, I determine it needs to allow a + sign at the start of the number, so ultimately the field-type is varchar(32).

If you don't need the +, then making the field varchar is superfluous.

And one constraint that you could put on a varchar would be

```
DECLARE @phone TABLE 
(
     phone_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
    ,phone_name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
    -- ,phone_number varchar(31) NULL CHECK (phone_number NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%') -- result of check may not be false
    -- ,phone_number varchar(31) NULL CHECK (phone_number NOT LIKE '%[^0-9+]%') -- result of check may not be false
    ,phone_number varchar(32) NULL CHECK 
    (
        (
            phone_number NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
            OR 
            (
                SUBSTRING(phone_number, 1, 1) = '+' 
                AND 
                SUBSTRING(phone_number, 2, 35) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
            )
        )
        AND phone_number <> '' 
    ) 

    --CONSTRAINT chk_phone CHECK (phone_number NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%') -- check that no number is not a digit 
);

INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
SELECT 1 AS phone_id, N'Person 1' AS pn, '123' AS phone_number; 

INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
SELECT 2 AS phone_id, N'Person 2' AS pn, '+123' AS phone_number; 

INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
SELECT 3 AS phone_id, N'Person 3' AS pn, '++123' AS phone_number; 

INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
SELECT 4 AS phone_id, N'Person 3' AS pn, '' AS phone_number; 

INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
SELECT 5 AS phone_id, N'Person 3' AS pn, NULL AS phone_number;
```

**Note that this allows NULL-values.** 
To disallow them, change the field-type from NULL to **NOT NULL**.

Also, note that you should always differenciate between the data, and the actual display value.

I would thus argue that the best way to store a phone number is this:

```
DECLARE @phone TABLE 
(
     phone_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
    ,phone_name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL 
    ,phone_number decimal(31,0) NULL CHECK 
    (
        -- phone_number > 0 AND 
        phone_number > 99
    ) 
);



INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
SELECT 1 AS phone_id, N'Person 1' AS pn, '112' AS phone_number; 

INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
SELECT 2 AS phone_id, N'Person 2' AS pn, '+12126879970' AS phone_number; 

-- INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
-- SELECT 3 AS phone_id, N'Person 3' AS pn, '-12126879970' AS phone_number; 

-- INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
-- SELECT 4 AS phone_id, N'Person 4' AS pn, '++12126879970' AS phone_number; 

-- INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
-- SELECT 5 AS phone_id, N'Person 5' AS pn, '+' AS phone_number; 

-- INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
-- SELECT 6 AS phone_id, N'Person 6' AS pn, '0' AS phone_number; 

-- INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
-- SELECT 7 AS phone_id, N'Person 7' AS pn, '+0' AS phone_number; 


INSERT INTO @phone ( phone_id, phone_name, phone_number )
SELECT 8 AS phone_id, N'Person 8' AS pn, '100.1' AS phone_number; 


SELECT * FROM @phone
```

Note that due to `+SOMETHING` being a valid number, you can also have a + in there. 
And values like 0.0 get truncated to 0. 
**One caveat**: this allows values such as '100.1' etc.

If you have a formatted phone-number as input that uses spaces and/or dashes, just do `REPLACE(REPLACE('YOUR_PHONE_NUMBER', ' ', ''), '-', '')`, and the constraint will help prevent any unwanted formatting-characters that are not caught by the replace from entering the DB (such as braces).