# Stored procedure to insert does not work: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert using a stored procedure but I'm getting

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

I'm working in SQL Server/Azure Data Studio.

This is the table I'm working with

```
CREATE TABLE Clinics 
(
    ClinicID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    ClinicName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ClinicPhoneNumber NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ClinicAddress NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ClinicCity NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ClinicState NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ClinicZipCode NVARCHAR(10),

    CONSTRAINT CHK_ClinicPhone 
        CHECK(ClinicPhoneNumber = FORMAT(CAST(ClinicPhoneNumber AS NUMERIC), '###-###-####')),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_ClinicZip 
        CHECK(ClinicZipCode = FORMAT(CAST(ClinicZipCode AS NUMERIC), '#####') 
        OR ClinicZipCode = FORMAT(CAST(ClinicZipCode AS NUMERIC), '#####-####'))
);
GO
```

Here is my code for the procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pInsertClinic
    (@ClinicName NVARCHAR(100),
     @ClinicPhoneNumber NVARCHAR(100),
     @ClinicAddress NVARCHAR(100),
     @ClinicCity NVARCHAR(100),
     @ClinicState NVARCHAR(100),
     @ClinicZipCode NVARCHAR(10))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RC int = 0;
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        SET NOCOUNT ON 

        INSERT INTO Clinics (ClinicName, ClinicPhoneNumber, ClinicAddress, 
                             ClinicCity, ClinicState, ClinicZipCode)
        VALUES (@ClinicName, @ClinicPhoneNumber, @ClinicAddress,
                @ClinicCity, @ClinicState, @ClinicZipCode)

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        SET @RC = +1
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF (@@Trancount > 0) 
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        PRINT Error_Message()
        SET @RC = -1
    END CATCH

    RETURN @RC;
END
GO
```

This is my exec code:

```
BEGIN 
    EXEC pInsertClinic
        @ClinicName = 'General Clinic',
        @ClinicPhoneNumber = '943-309-3094',
        @ClinicAddress = '9876 fourth st',
        @ClinicCity = 'Seattle',
        @ClinicState = 'WA',
        @ClinicZipCode = '98118';
    SELECT * FROM vClinics;
END
GO
```

The name, phone, and address info should all be equal to what is in the exec. The clinic ID should be automatically assigned as an integer

Comment: `CAST('943-309-3094' AS NUMERIC)` fails...

Comment: Maybe you want `FORMAT(CAST(replace('943-309-3094', '-', '') AS NUMERIC), '###-###-####')`

Answer (score 0):

Table Structure should be like this..

```
CREATE TABLE Clinics 
(
    ClinicID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    ClinicName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ClinicPhoneNumber NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ClinicAddress NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ClinicCity NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ClinicState NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ClinicZipCode NVARCHAR(10),

    CONSTRAINT CHK_ClinicPhone 
         CHECK(ClinicPhoneNumber = FORMAT(CAST(REPLACE(ClinicPhoneNumber,'-','') AS NUMERIC), '###-###-####')),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_ClinicZip 
         CHECK(ClinicZipCode = FORMAT(CAST(ClinicZipCode AS NUMERIC), '#####') 
            OR ClinicZipCode = FORMAT(CAST(ClinicZipCode AS NUMERIC), '#####-####'))
 );
 GO
```

Comment: Explain what you've changed - and why?

Comment: Changed this code CHECK(ClinicPhoneNumber = FORMAT(CAST(ClinicPhoneNumber AS NUMERIC), '###-###-####')),                                  as                                                                                                                                                   CHECK(ClinicPhoneNumber = FORMAT(CAST(REPLACE(ClinicPhoneNumber,'-','') AS NUMERIC), '###-###-####')),

Comment: because we passed the value for phone number is '943-309-3094'.When try to cast into numeric,it raise an error.So first i replace this  '943-309-3094' to  '9433093094' using replace function.then we can cast it into numeric with out error..

Answer (score 0):

Start over. And this time THINK about your datatypes first before you do anything else. The problems:

- Zip code is nullable. Why? The constraint, if working, would not allow it. And why nvarchar? You intend to store numeric characters only.
- Stop with the insane naming convention. Prefacing every column name with the name of the table will only increase the amount of work everyone needs to do to write queries.
- Phone number is nvarchar(100). Why? The constraint, if working, would not allow it. And why nvarchar? You intend to store numeric characters only.
- State is nvarchar(100). Why? You intend to store the state abbreviation. Sometimes copy/paste is not your friend. And why nvarchar?
- No reason to start a transaction that contains a single DML statement.
- Do not use "print" to communicate errors to the caller. Print will generate a resultset - which requires calling apps to be written to interrogate that resultset to know if an error occurred (and what type of error). Either rethrow the error and just let the caller catch it without your try/catch. Erland has a comprehensive discussion of [error handling](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) - probably over your head but keep the link as a reference (and he also discusses other common but complicated issues).
- The last statement in your test script selects from vClinics. You're just not paying attention. If you have a view (presumably, based on the name), you did not provide it in your DDL. If you don't have a view, then ... who knows.

For this and for any other problem you might encounter (or question you might have), your first response should be to search the internet. Enforcing rules about the content of strings is a common question and you can find MANY examples with very simple searches. And in this case, you can simply search on "stackoverflow constraint phone number" to find past discussions. So relying on [one of those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045875/constraint-for-phone-number-in-sql-server), we can use something like the following.

```
set nocount on; 
if object_id('tempdb..#Clinics') is not null 
drop table #Clinics;
go

CREATE TABLE #Clinics 
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    Address NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    City NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    State CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    ZipCode VARCHAR(10) not null 
);
GO

insert #Clinics (Name, PhoneNumber, Address, City, State, ZipCode) 
values ('Text Clinic', '111-2222', '123 Main Street', 'Seattle', 'WA', '11111');
select * from #Clinics; 
go

alter table #Clinics add constraint chk_phone check (PhoneNumber like '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') 
go

insert #Clinics (Name, PhoneNumber, Address, City, State, ZipCode) 
values ('Bad number', '1112222', '987 Main Street', 'Seattle', 'WA', '11111'); -- error
insert #Clinics (Name, PhoneNumber, Address, City, State, ZipCode) 
values ('Good Clinic', '123-4444', '987 Main Street', 'Seattle', 'WA', '11111');
insert #Clinics (Name, PhoneNumber, Address, City, State, ZipCode) 
values ('Short Number', '123-444', '987 Main Street', 'Seattle', 'WA', '11111'); -- error
insert #Clinics (Name, PhoneNumber, Address, City, State, ZipCode) 
values ('Short Exchange', '13-4445', '987 Main Street', 'Seattle', 'WA', '11111'); --error
insert #Clinics (Name, PhoneNumber, Address, City, State, ZipCode) 
values ('Bad Separator', '213+4445', '987 Main Street', 'Seattle', 'WA', '11111'); --error
insert #Clinics (Name, PhoneNumber, Address, City, State, ZipCode) 
values ('Letters', '213-A445', '987 Main Street', 'Seattle', 'WA', '11111'); --error
select * from #Clinics;
```

This shows the approach - you would need to extend it for a complete implementation. But before you do that, I have to question why. This sort of thing is typically better implemented in the GUI. Usually one uses a mask that will automatically enforce this. An app can also provide much better guidance and error handling for basic entry mistakes - an ugly and difficult to read native sql server error is hardly user-friendly.

You should also carefully reconsider the enforced use of a certain formatting for storage. Some people prefer to see phone numbers as (999)123-4567. I've seen many examples where periods are used instead of dashes. You are making a commitment here that will be difficult to change at a later date.

And one last comment. You can't do everything at once. Ignore the use of a procedure for now. Define your table and verify that your constraints work correctly using DML statements that encompass both good and bad data. Once that works, then you add the complication of a stored procedure. Once that works, then you incorporate the use of the procedure into your application. That approach applies to any type of code development - you don't build on a foundation that has not be tested and verified.