# Select most suitable data type in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create a database for  a hotel reservation system.I want to store the phone number of the  customer .What is the best data type for this?I like to use `char(10)`.But I have a doubt about the size of the data type since the length of the t.p number varies in different countries.Whats the best option for this?

Comment: so whats the question the data type or amount of characters?

Comment: @yesitsme amount of characters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/723603/4535386

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the longest possible worldwide phone number I should consider in SQL varchar(length) for phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723587/whats-the-longest-possible-worldwide-phone-number-i-should-consider-in-sql-varc)

Comment: Why `CHAR` in the first place, rather than VARCHAR? I don't think that padding phone numbers to a fixed size is actually helpful for anything, esp. since you'll be storing numbers from different countries.

Answer (score 0):

Many people will enter the phone number with the plus prefix (+), the IDD (country code), area code and phone number.  Plus they may add spaces and/or parenthesis in various places.

Unless your are using a phone number parsing library, such as https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber, I suggest `char(32)`.