# fscanf delimiters - accepting spaces, character limit

Tags: c, string, file, delimiter

I'm struggling with importing lines from a text file into a C program. Below is the text I'm trying to import:

```
1000|Larry Normal|CELL|3048005191
1001|Shelly Nopers|CELL|3048005191
1002|Shelly Schnats|HOME|3649155831
1003|Terry Crews|HOME|3932281123
```

Delimited by | and with spaces in names.

Here's the code I'm using below:

```
    FILE* patientFile = NULL;

    int patientNum;
    char patientName[15];
    char phoneDescription[5];
    char phoneNumber[11];

    patientFile = fopen("patientData.txt", "r");

    if (patientFile != NULL)
    {
        while (fscanf(patientFile, "%d|%14s|%4s|%10s\n", &patientNum, patientName, phoneDescription, phoneNumber ) != EOF)
        {
            printf("%d %s %s %s\n", patientNum, patientName, phoneDescription, phoneNumber);
        }


        fclose(patientFile);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed to open patients file\n");
    }
```

While the file can be read, I'm getting this as my output:

```
1024 Larry  ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
1024 Larry  ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
1024 Larry  ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
1024 Larry  ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
1024 Larry  ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
```

Repeating forever. Can anyone offer insight for where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Your loop should be `while (fscanf(patientFile, "%d|%14s|%4s|%10s\n", &patientNum, patientName, phoneDescription, phoneNumber ) == 4)`. You don't really care if you've hit the end of the file, but you do care if not all of the arguments were converted. You probably don't want the `\n` in the format string. You might consider reading the file line by line with `fgets` and using `sscanf` to parse it. That would allow you to process all lines that parsed correctly but skip ones that did not.

Comment: Hey Retired Ninja, Thanks for the reply!

I tried changing it to == 4 instead of EOF at the end, and now I have a new problem - it doesn't seem to read through the file at all. Any advice?

Comment: The `%14s` specifier will only match a single word. It will not match `Larry Normal`, it will only match `Larry`. You may want to use `%14[^|]` instead, in order to match everything up to the `|`.

Comment: Yes, now you know that you aren't parsing any lines properly. A format string of `"%d|%14[^|]|%4[^|]|%10s"` should work but is fragile and will break if any of the fields are too long. I would read the line, use `strtok` to split it into pieces, and then copy the values from those pieces with `strncpy` to limit the length to destination width - 1 and manually ensure the last destination character was a 0.

Answer (score 0):

**`"%s"` insufficient to read a *name***

`"%14s"` will only read and save `"Larry"` of `"Larry Normal"`.  Instead use `"14s[^|]"` to read to a `"|"`.

**Code checks against only 1 undesired return value**

As `fscanf()` may return values other than `EOF` and `4`, rather than check against one of the undesired return values, check against the desired one.

```
 // while (fscanf(patientFile, "%d|%14s|%4s|%10s\n", ...) != EOF)
 while (fscanf(patientFile, "%d|%14s|%4s|%10s\n", ...) == 4)
```

**Advanced: Better end-of-line detection via `fgets()`**

`"%d"`, `"%s"` ignore and consume leading white-space including `'\n'`.  Better to read a *line* into a buffer and then parse.

```
// "%d|%14s|%4s|%10s\n"
#define LINE_SIZE (11 + 1 + 14 + 1 + 4 + 1 + 10 + 1 + 1)
char buf[LINE_SIZE * 2]; // Do not be stingy on potential line sizes.

while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, patientFile) && 
    sscanf(buf, "%d|%14[^|]|%4[^|]|%10[^\n]", 
    &patientNum, patientName, phoneDescription, phoneNumber) == 4) {
  printf("%d %s %s %s\n", patientNum, patientName, phoneDescription, phoneNumber);
}
```

---

Robust code would also check for trailing text after the phone number, excessive long lines, etc.

Perhaps also start checking for acceptable text like `"%10[^0-9#*]"` instead of `"%10[^\n]"` for the phone number.  See also [longest possible worldwide phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4729239/2410359).

Answer (score -2):

Try this pattern `"%d|%[^|]|%[^|]|%s\n"` instead. `[^|]` means read all characters till the `|`. `%s` will not work cuz `|` is not white-space.

Ref: https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

Comment: By removing all of the width specifiers you've opened this up to 3 potential buffer overflows.