# Phone number formatting with a dot after the country code

Tags: floating-point, phone-number, rounding-error

My domain registrar asks for a phone number in the following format: `+358.401234567` (where `358` is the country code, `40` is the area code and the rest is the local phone number).

To me personally this format is unfamiliar, and I couldn't find it used anywhere other than WHOIS domain information. I was trying to find any reference to this specific format specification, but unsuccessfully. Maybe this format is required by ICANN, but I couldn't find any proof of this. Is this phone number notation standardized?

What is most concerning, is that getting this information back from the registrar's REST API, the value is returned as a float like this: `{ "phone": 358.401234567 }`. Can this lead to rounding errors when storing the value as a float instead of a string?

Comment: Re “returned as a float like this: `{ "phone": 358.401234567 }`”: `358.401234567` is not a “float.” It is a string of characters. If interpreted as a numeral, it is a fixed-point representation, not a floating-point representation, because it has the point, `.`, in a fixed position, after the third digit. A floating-point representation consists of a significand and an exponent, where the exponent tells you where the point goes. Do not use “float” to mean “non-integer number”; that is not what it means. And phone numbers generally should not be interpreted as numerals at all.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I don't know for sure what data type does the internal registrar's database use, just assuming it is a floating point value based on JSON returned by their API.

Comment: @EricPostpischil presume you know this, but some significant JSON parsers (e.g. JavaScript's `JSON.parse`) don't provide a way to control the data type that numeric values decode to.  I.e. these values will almost certainly end up in IEEE754 binary64 floats unless something puts quotes around them.

Comment: @tpimh "Can this lead to rounding errors when storing the value as a float instead of a string?" --> Yes.  Do not use floating point for this task.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I couldn't actually find any number that would cause rounding errors, however trailing zeros turned out to be a problem. I am reporting this to my service provider. If you have any suggestion of a phone number that can be rounded incorrectly (I suppose, it should be pretty long), I can test it.

Comment: @tpimh Whole numbers > 9,007,199,254,740,992 are not exactly encodable as a `double`.  The longest phone number is [15 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4729239/2410359).  Yet additional digits exits for a call prefix, [up to 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_call_prefixes) and [suffix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_telephone_system) (maybe up to 11).

Comment: @tpimh IAC, since the "telephone number" may need to include `"#"`, `"*"`, pauses (perhasp as `','`), `'-'` or `' '` for presentation, using a string is a good alternative.

Comment: @tpimh _Select_ whole numbers > 9,007,199,254,740,992 are not exactly encodable as a `double`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Unfortunately, I can't test this. I tested and it seems that I can only use country codes from 1 to 999.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a string, not a numeric value for a phone number.

If in any case, you need a numeric value, assuming that the binary64 format (double precision) is used internally on the machine, then, if *d* ⩽ 15, it is possible to convert a *d*-digit decimal number to binary64, and you will retrieve the original value if you convert the binary64 number back to a *d*-digit decimal number. This is because 1+*d*·log(10)/log(2) ⩽ 53 (where 53 is the precision of binary64). Be careful of the trailing zeros if the number of digits of the phone number is variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will definitely check with a phone number with trailing zeroes.